# Как запустить объект в виде потока, если использовать модуль threading в python

Tags: python, многопоточность, threading

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class Main(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
    
    def startInfinityCycle(self):
        while True:
            print("Aaaaaa")
            sleep(1)

def Second():
    while True:
        print("Bbbbbb")
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main = Main()
    # main.startInfinityCycle()
    # print("TEST1")

    second = Thread(target=Second)
    second.start()
    print("TEST2")
```

Если запускать в виде функции, то все верно, и, помимо бесконечного принта, я вижу **"TEST2"** в консоли. Но если запустить то, что закомментировано, то код стопится на вызове метода у объекта в бесконечном цикле, дальше код **не выполняется**

Сам вопрос - как заставить работать все это на основе класса?

Answer (score 2):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.startInfinityCycle()
    print("TEST1")
```

Так вы запускаете метод `startInfinityCycle` без всяких потоков, просто как обычную функцию. Вы её  вызываете и ждёте, когда она закончится. Поэтому `TEST1` и не печатается - до него не доходит управление в основном потоке программы.

Правильный код:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class Main(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("Aaaaaa")
            sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    print("TEST1")
    main.join()
```

Вывод:

```
Aaaaaa
AaaaaaTEST1

Aaaaaa
Aaaaaa
Aaaaaa
...
```

В чём тут дело. Чтобы правильно запустить функцию в классе, унаследованном от `Thread`, нужно "перегрузить" метод класса `run` этой функцией. Кроме того, нужно не забывать делать `join` запущенному потоку, иначе он закончится вместе с основной программой, возможно, даже не успев толком запуститься.

Comment: Спасибо, для меня совсем показалось неочевидным

Comment: @jorlyf Работа с потоками - штука непростая, к ней нужно попривыкнуть. Нужно научиться себе как-то в мозгу представлять, как оно параллельно работает :)

Answer (score 1):

В `Thread` в потоке будет выполняться **только** код в методе `run`, а чтобы поток был запущен так же используется метод `start`

Пример:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


class Main(Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("Aaaaaa")
            sleep(1)


def Second():
    while True:
        print("Bbbbbb")
        sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.start()
    print("TEST1")

    second = Thread(target=Second)
    second.start()
    print("TEST2")
```

Comment: Может всё же `join`-ы добавить? )

Comment: @CrazyElf, а зачем в потоках циклы все-равно бесконечные?

Comment: А если основная программа закончится, порождённые потоки останутся? Ну и вообще, зачем учить плохому стилю )

Comment: @CrazyElf, чтобы потоки дохли вместе с основным потоком их нужно объявлять демонами, типа `main.daemon = True`, а так, не вижу смысла тут добавлять `join` :)